# how to delete 2 tables records in sql using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
  delete dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKMST, dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKDTL 
  from dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKMST sam 
  inner join dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKDTL sad on sam.CBM_COCODE = sad.CBD_COCODE 
  where sam.CBM_COCODE='13'
```

This query showing me error on `,` comma between tables

Help me thanks

Comment: I am trying to delete 13 in both tables

Comment: DELETE FROM dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKMST WHERE CBM_COCODE= '13' and then DELETE FROM dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKDTL WHERE CBD_COCODE = '13' Again giving me error on then statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **two statements** - one single SQL statement **cannot** delete from two tables!

```
DELETE FROM dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKMST WHERE CBM_COCODE = 13
DELETE FROM dbo.GL_CHEQBOOKDTL WHERE CBM_COCODE = 13
```